# Docker for nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I'm getting started with `Docker` and `docker-compose`

My first step was to build a stack with 2 containers : 1 for nginx and 1 for php-fpm

With that config, it's working

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - "9090:80"
        volumes:
            - ./conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
            - ./content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
        links:
            - php
    php:
        image: php:7.1.8-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
```

In `/content` I have both a `index.html` and `phpinfo.php`

I can get both pages in my browser.

But I don't understand why I have to put all my pages in both containers ?

If I don't put the volume for the `php service`, the index.html is displaying but not the phpinfo.php (File not found.)

If I don't put the volume for the `web service`, the nginx index.html is displaying but not the phpinfo.php (404 error).

So now if I want to deploy a wordpress site I will have to copy all the files in both containers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad configuration. Good practice is to separate all processes, so you should have 3 services: nginx, php-fpm and php. Source code should be ONLY inside php container.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So the php container should be a data container ?

Comment: Yes, PHP for data, PHP-fpm is something like "bridge" between php and nginx and NGINX handles requests.

Comment: @mitch, 2 services actually, nginx and php +fpm, because php and fpm needs to be in same container. So you can probably update the answer

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me, I am not sure why it is accepted.  Am I misunderstanding, can you clarify?  `php-fpm` is ["a FastCGI implementation for PHP"](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) - you do **not** need it **and** a PHP service, which is what you suggest.  So OP's config with 2 containers is correct - or at least a completely valid option.  And OP has already explained that having data only inside the PHP container (or in fact either) does not work ... @tweetysat maybe you can comment, did you accept this bcs it actually solved your problem?